# All column names are invalid Magento

Tags: mysql, database, magento, import-from-excel

I exported the products from my old website and tried to imported into new website but I am getting this very weird error

```
Column names: "_absolute_price", "_absolute_weight", "_sku_policy", "_custom_option_template_id", "_custom_option_view_mode", "_custom_option_customoptions_is_onetime", "_custom_option_image_path", "_custom_option_customer_groups", "_custom_option_qnty_input", "_custom_option_in_group_id", "_custom_option_is_dependent", "_custom_option_div_class", "_custom_option_image_mode", "_custom_option_exclude_first_image", "_custom_option_description", "_custom_option_default_text", "_custom_option_sku_policy", "_custom_option_row_customoptions_qty", "_custom_option_row_image_data", "_custom_option_row_default", "_custom_option_row_in_group_id", "_custom_option_row_dependent_ids", "_custom_option_row_weight", "_custom_option_row_cost", "_custom_option_row_special_data", "_custom_option_row_tier_data" are invalid
```

All column names are invalid.how? 
I have tried opening the `.csv` file and saving it as `utf-8` encoded but did not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to remove first underscore ('_') from all these attributes.

Comment: ok i will try and let you know but i have exported this file from a working website why it is causing problem while importing